# Printing Unicode in eclipse Pydev console and in Idle

Tags: python, eclipse, unicode, console, pydev

My configuration: Win7 + Python 2.6 + eclipse + PyDev

How do I enable Unicode print statements in:

1. PyDev console in eclipse
2. Idle Python GUI

Example print statement:

```
print(u"שלום עולם")
```

This comes out as:

```
ùìåí òåìí
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For eclipse unicode console support:

1. Add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to `eclipse.ini` which is in the eclipse install directory.
2. In eclipse - `Run\Run Configurations\Python Run\configuration\Common\` make sure UTF-8 is selected
3. In eclipse - `Window\Preferences\General\Workspace\Text file encoding\` making sure UTF-8 is selected
4. In `[python install path]\Lib\site.py` - change from `encoding = "ascii"` to `encoding = "utf-8"`
5. Make sure you're using unicode supporting fonts in eclipse - `Window\Preferences\Appearance\Colors and Fonts\Debug\Console font\Edit`

In the installation I did all of the above:

```
print(u"שלום עולם")         # Doesn't work
print("שלום עולם")          # Works
```

For django models:

```
print(my_model.my_field)                 # Doesn't work
print(my_model.my_field.encode('utf-8')) # Works
```

Comment: This worked great for me, was looking around a lot for this. For me it sufficed to edit the eclipse.ini. But all the other settings were already set to UTF-8 except the site.py, which was set to `ascii`. But that didn't really make a difference I noticed.

Comment: Yeah, took me a while to stumble on this too - thanks for posting!  For me, I just did step 2. and that worked fine for my purposes.

Comment: The console doesn't correctly communicate what encoding it uses; set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to tell Python explicitly.

Comment: It was step 2 that fixed my problem as well.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the a [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346518/cant-make-eclipse-luna-pydev-console-use-utf-8) in Eclipse Luna 4.0.4 with Python 3.4.1 and PyDev 3.6.0. I tried the steps given above, and a few others, and was getting nowhere.

What worked for me was, in Eclipse, in **Preferences** —> **PyDev** —> **Interpreters** —> **Python Interpreter**, in the **Environment** tab, I added the environment variable **PYTHONIOENCODING** and specified its value as **utf-8**.

That did the trick for me…

Answer (score 0):

PYTHONIOENCODING is a pretty good generic way of fixing this problem. However, the Eclipse way of setting the locale of its console is as follows:

Set the **Run Configuration** encoding:

1. Edit **Run Configuration**
2. Click on **"Common"** tab
3. Set Encoding to **"UTF-8"**