# Can't make Eclipse (Luna) PyDev console use UTF-8

Tags: eclipse, unicode, pydev

In Eclipse Luna (4.0.4) / Python 3.4.1  I can't get the PyDev 3.6.0 console to work with Unicode despite having tried several recommended corrective steps.

I attempted this example in Dive Into Python 3: http://www.diveintopython3.net/files.html

If I do the example's *a_file.read()*, the PyDev console displays:

> 'Dive Into Python \u662f\u4e3a\u6709\u7ecf\u9a8c......' instead of 'Dive Into Python 是为有经验的程序员编写的一本...'

If I paste the Chinese characters into the PyDev console ala *cstring = '是为有经验的程序员编写的一本'*, then in the console type "cstring ENTER', I again get '\u662f\u4e3a\u6709\u7ecf\u9a8c...'

If I then try *print(cstring)*, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-13: character maps to

**I don't know what do do with that information.** The *cp1252.py* bit is at the heart of my confusion because I've told Eclipse and PyDev to use UTF-8 in every place I can find to do that, beginning with the information in the following:

[Printing Unicode in eclipse Pydev console and in Idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023972/printing-unicode-in-eclipse-pydev-console-and-in-idle#answer-3026611)

However, I cannot modify "site.py" as described in those steps because *[EclipseInstallDir]/lib/site.py* does not contain "encoding = ".

I can't figure out what to do next.

Comment: Could you try and add `encoding = ...` to your `site.py` file content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! (At least for Python 3.4.1, Eclipse Luna 4.0.4, PyDev 3.6.0.)

In Eclipse, in **Preferences** —>  **PyDev** —> **Interpreters** —> **Python Interpreter**, in the **Environment** tab, I added the environment variable **PYTHONIOENCODING** and specified its value as **utf-8**.

The PyDev Interactive Console now properly displays the aforementioned Chinese characters (and Thai characters, too).

Comment: Uh-oh: The most recent "upgrade" to PyDev for Eclipse 3.7.1.201409021729 broke the Unicode functionality...

Comment: is there some bug report?

Comment: I just created ticket 442 on PyDev's Brainwy Tracker: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/

Answer (score 3):

For regular runs:

The problem there is that the PYTHONIOENCODING is overridden by PyDev based on the encoding you used in the run configuration (which is the encoding used by the console view too -- so, it'd make no sense having a PYTHONIOENCODING with a value and the allocated console in the PyDev side with another value).

You can change the encoding you're using for a run configuration in:
Run > Run configurations > common > encoding.

By default it'll use the encoding of the file being launched (you can change the default encoding for the workspace in general > workspace > text file encoding).

---

For interactive console runs:

For interactive console runs there's currently no API to change the encoding in the java side, so, one has to start Eclipse itself in a VM that uses UTF-8 by default... In practice, this means that you have to add:

-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

to the vmargs of Eclipse in eclipse.ini (and in this case it's also recommended to set the PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable in the related interpreter and set it to UTF-8).

Comment: Actually, no. I had that set to UTF-8 by virtue of it being the default inherited from the top-level project folder. And it didn't work. The only thing that finally did work was setting PYTHONIOENCODING to utf-8 as described. And that worked GREAT until the most recent update to PyDev.

Comment: Have you tried what I said with the latest version? (previously PyDev did some hacks with sys.setdefaultencoding and the last version started using PYTHONIOENCODING properly).

Comment: Just to be clear, the problem isn't in the output console PyDev displays when Run-ing a .py file. The problem is in the PyDev interactive console with the command line that begins with ">>>". Having upgraded PyDev again this morning, the problem with the interactive console remains as described. PYTHONIOENCODING fixed that display issue two revs ago but then it got broken. Still broken after this morning's upgrade to 3.8.0.201409251235. Anyhow, the Run config's Common --> Encoding setting already = UTF-8 by virtue of it being inherited from the project folder. Or?

Comment: Ok, just added the current state of affairs to the answer (I hadn't understood that the issue was in the interactive console... the answer I gave was really only valid for regular runs), so, currently you have to start Eclipse itself setting the encoding you want in eclipse.ini... Please report that as an issue in https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/ (i.e.: provide a way to configure the encoding for interactive console).

Comment: Per your instructions created new ticket 454 (https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/454). That ticket references this StackOverflow thread.

Comment: Ok, thanks, now, just to make explicit, the current workaround is setting -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in the vmargs in eclipse.ini

Comment: Hasn't worked. I edited eclipse.ini as follows: -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 I restarted eclipse and pasted this into the interactive >>> console: cString = Dive Into Python 是为有经验的程序员编写的一本 Python 书。 >>> cString ENTER returned 'Dive Into Python æ˜¯ä¸ºæœ‰ç»�éªŒçš„ç¨‹åº�å‘˜ç¼–å†™çš„ä¸€æœ¬ Python ä¹¦ã€‚' Sigh...

Comment: AND if I remove the PYTHONIOENCODING setting, the result = 'Dive Into Python \u662f\u4e3a\u6709\u7ecf\u9a8c\...'