# How to display unicode string in its natural language in PyDev console

Tags: python, eclipse, unicode, pydev

I have a unicode string that i retrieve from an online server. I want to be able to display it on the console in its original form, but i always get gibberish.

Below is what My PyDev console:

```
>>> n=u'\u05d9'
>>> n
u'\u05d9'
>>> print n
×™
```

When I use an online service such as [Online Unicode Converter](http://unicode.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php) I get the true representation of that string. (In this case the Hebrew י character)

In short: How can I make my console interpret the unicode string like the online service.

I tried all suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023972/printing-unicode-in-eclipse-pydev-console-and-in-idle), but the problem persists.

Comment: Your console is incorrectly configured; Python thinks it needs to write UTF-8, but clearly that's not the case; your console instead interprets the bytes as CP1252.

Comment: Tried all guidelines there, but the problem persists

Comment: Can you add what you tried to your question here? Not just state that you tried, but describing *what* you tried is important. I'm sure your question can then be re-opened.

Comment: Add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to eclipse.ini which is in the eclipse install directory.
    In eclipse - Run\Run Configurations\Python Run\configuration\Common\ make sure UTF-8 is selected
    In eclipse - Window\Preferences\General\Workspace\Text file encoding\ making sure UTF-8 is selected
    In [python install path]\Lib\site.py - change from encoding = "ascii" to encoding = "utf-8"
    Make sure you're using unicode supporting fonts in eclipse - Window\Preferences\Appearance\Colors and Fonts\Debug\Console font\Edit

Comment: in Eclipse, in Preferences —> PyDev —> Interpreters —> Python Interpreter, in the Environment tab, I added the environment variable PYTHONIOENCODING and specified its value as utf-8.

Comment: Edit your question, don't put that in the comments.

Comment: I already edited. i added a link to the other question instead of copying all the guidelines from there. If you think I should copy them here, I can do that.

Comment: I know you already edited, but that doesn't tell someone familiar with Eclipse / PyDev (not me) what you actually *did*. Perhaps you missed a crucial detail, etc.