# Python endswith() reverse?

Tags: python, excel

I am using the win32com.client to read an Excel file and I would like to find everything NOT ending with "some string" in the value(s) I have in:

```
ws.Cells(i, 8).Value
```

Since I do not know the workaround for endswith(), I tried to also search by the value length which could also do the job, but I cannot call len() on ws.Cells(i, 8).Value because I get an 'unicode' error. I also tried to convert the value to a string without luck.

Basically I would like to do:

```
if len(ws.Cells(i, 8).Value) > 255:
    ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = ws.Cells(i, 8).Value + " (Issues Here)"
```

I appreciate any support I can get on this.

Comment: "I cannot call len() on ws.Cells(i, 8).Value because I get an 'unicode' error." What is the exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `not` in the if statement.

```
string_list = ["this ends in some string", "this string does not"]

for string in string_list:
    if not string.endswith('some string'):
        print string, ". GOOD!"
```

result:

```
this string does not. GOOD!
```

Comment: Thank you!
Can you also help me with the len() option, if one would want to use it?
I am really curious how that could be accomplished with a unicode value.

Comment: I can't replicate your error. How are you calling it? it should be `len(ws.Cells(i, 8).Value)`

Comment: Also, did you try using `.Text`instead of `.Value`?

This might be useful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767898/how-to-read-excel-unicode-characters-using-python

Comment: Sir, it was my bad! Sorry!
I also had empty cells so I needed the extra condition of    `ws.Cells(i, 8).Value is not None`;

Thank you again.