# Process non-ascii characters such as pound in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding, escaping

I wanna process a sentence such as:
"The gift costs nearly £100"

The sentence is in a text file. I read it in python and when I print it I get:

```
print "text",text
text The gift costs nearly Â£100.
```

I tried to replace it with the code (and when I finish processing I would use another function unmapstrangechars to get the original data):

```
def mapstrangechars(text):
    text = text.replace("Â£","1pound1 ")
    return text 

def unmapstrangechars(text):
    text = text.replace("1pound1 ","Â£")    
    return text
```

But I do get an error saying that Â£ is not an acii character. How can I fix it?

It would be helpfull to learn at least how cound I replace a non acii char with anything specific to this char, so i could recover it letter.
For example:
original:The gift costs nearly Â£100.
copy1: The gift costs nearly 11pound11 100.
output: The gift costs nearly $100.

output is actually:

```
print text
```

Whole code(in txt file it says "The gift costs nearly £100."):

```
if 1==1:     
    import os
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    rel_path = "results/article.txt"
    abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)       
    thefile = open(abs_file_path)
    text = thefile.read()


    print "text",text


    def mapstrangechars(text):
        #text = text.replace("fdfdsfds","1pound1 ")
        return text

    def unmapstrangechars(text):
        #text = text.replace("1pound1 ","fdfdsfds")    
        return text  

    text = mapstrangechars(text)

    #process the text

    text = unmapstrangechars(text)    
    print "text",text  #this is output
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE like Eclipse or Pycharm, or IDLE to run your program and view the output? When I run your code on command-line I do see `text The gift costs nearly £100` output twice as expected. So perhaps the environment your running your script in is not configured to handle those fonts.

Comment: I use eclipse with pydev. How do I change these setting?

Comment: These answers may help: [Printing Unicode in eclipse Pydev console and in Idle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023972/printing-unicode-in-eclipse-pydev-console-and-in-idle)

Comment: actually I use python 2.7.3 ... it could be that 3 can handle the problem and 2.7.3 not.

Comment: yeah maybe, but I doubt it since it works for me on 2.7.10

Comment: will try in different editors.

Comment: seems like adding # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- helps

Comment: Cool, does doing that answer the original question? Or are there other problems your having

Comment: Have to recheck if it works in the main code, this is just a snippet.

Comment: `# -- coding: utf-8` only helps if you're source code is `utf-8` encoded and contains non-ascii. Your workaround introduced the requirement to have non-ascii in your source code. The proper fix does not require any manipulation

Comment: Also, you should check the encoding of your file before using `# -- coding: utf-8`. It should always matching the encoding of your file.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the encoding of your text file is 'utf-8', but your terminal/IDE is probably in Windows-1252 encoding.

In UTF-8, the pound sign is encoded as two bytes: `0xc2 0xa3`
If you opened your file in a hex editor, this is what you'd see.

When you printed it, your terminal/IDE is interpreting `0xc2 0xa3` as `windows-1252`. Like other 8bit codepages, `windows-1252` expects each byte maps to a character. Therefore, when `0xc2 0xa3` is interpreted as `windows-1252` and each byte is mapped to a character instead, the following happens:

`0xc2` displays as `Â`
`0xa3` displays as `£`

The solution is to decode your text file to a special Python string type called "Unicode String". Once you have a Python Unicode String, Python is able to re-encode it for your terminal type. I.e, Python will decode UTF-8, then encode to `windows-1252`.

To achieve this, use the `io` module `open()` method and pass in an `encoding` attribute:

```
import io
thefile = io.open(abs_file_path, encoding="utf-8")
```

When you `read()` from `thefile`, you will get a `<type 'unicode'>`. It will function just like a regular string. When you pass it to `print`, Python will automatically encode it so it displays on your terminal.

You no longer need `mapstrangechars()` and `unmapstrangechars()`

**Note:** This is particular to **Python 2.x**, where `open()` defaults to opening in binary mode. Python 3 opens in text mode by default and will use the locale/language settings to determine the correct encoding if not given.